# How to check if a String[] index exists?

Tags: java

I have a `String[]` and I would like to check if an index exists in it (such as String[3]).

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (arr != null && i >= 0 && i < arr.length) {
  // arr[i] exists
}
```

If `arr` is an array of objects, you may also need to check whether `arr[i]` is null:

```
if (arr != null && i >= 0 && i < arr.length && arr[i] != null) {
  // arr[i] exists and is not null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An existing index doesn't necessarily mean a **non-null** array entry, be careful.

```
String[] array = ...
int index = 3;

if(array.length > index && index >= 0)
  // it exists.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public boolean indexExists(String[] array,int index){
    if(array!=null && index >= 0 && index < array.length)
        return true;
    else 
       return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean DoesIndexExists(String []arr, int index){
   if( arr != null && index >= 0 && index < arr.length &&  )
       return true;

   return false;
}
```

Comment: You should really check that `arr != null` **before** trying to get it's length.